# Attaching multiple emoji pickers (buttons) to multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 6 tabs on a page, all with a textarea. For each textarea I would like to add an emoji-button that when clicked, opens an emoji dictionary, the user selects one and it appends the text in the relevant textarea.

I am using https://emoji-button.js.org/ and can get it working for one emoji button on one textarea using the following:

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="postCopy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="postCopy">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 well">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control caption-box" name="caption" id="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <img style="cursor:pointer;" id="emoji" src="/assets/images/emoji.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#emoji');
  const picker = new EmojiButton();

  picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
      document.querySelector('textarea').value += emoji;
  });

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    picker.togglePicker(button);
  });
});
```

How can I create a new emoji button for each of the 6 textareas without simply replicating the code 6 times?

The ids of the textarea (#caption) and emoji div (#emoji) are the same for each tab pane, but if it's easier I can change them.

I have tried combinations of `.each()` and `.next()` but this isn't my expertise so hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: ID's are unique in a page by definition, think of them like an address. Use common classes for like elements

Comment: As I mentioned, I can change them but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Sure it will...query for the className and loop over the collection to add event listeners to each one

Comment: You are querying by tag type of textarea, so it'd only work for the first textarea. You need to assign a different ID to each text area and select the different ID (queryElementByID) in the function.

Comment: @KaseyChang - thanks, I understand. However my question is more about achieving this without replicating the code 6 times.

Comment: You don't need to replicate the code six times. You just need to change this line:

   document.queryElementById(thisId).value += emoji;

where you change thisId to whatever Id you want to point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a nice solution by using the .active class of the tab-pane. This appends the visible textarea with the selected emoji (note: you only need one emoji button)

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#emoji');
  const picker = new EmojiButton();

  picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
  $('.active textarea').append(emoji);
  });

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    picker.togglePicker(button);
  });
});
```